# Oracle Forms - Use TAB key to move down records

Tags: oracleforms

Using Oracle Forms, How can a block/form be configured to have the TAB key move down records? Shift+TAB to move UP records.

We are storing data values in tables which are "tall" rather than "wide."  Each attribute for an item will be stored in a table in it's own record.

Simplified example: Columns in table are ITEM, ATTRIBUTE, VALUE.  When displayed on the form, only the VALUE field is editable.  If we display all records for ITEM A, we will have 10 records, each for its own ATTRIBUTE. I want the user to be able to move from attribute 1 to attribute 10 using the TAB key rather than the down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ITEM` and `ATTRIBUTE` columns in block non navigable. Cursor will remain only in `VALUE` column.

Create `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger on `VALUE` column with code

```
next_record;
```

Create `KEY-PREV-ITEM` trigger on `VALUE` column with code

```
previous_record;
```

Instead of triggers you can set block property Navigation Style to Change Record. Because your block has only one navigable item, cursor will move to next record.